# Pong Game Score Keeping in Pygame

Tags: function, python-3.x, count, pygame

Here is the code segment from my program which controls the score keeping. The problem is that it adds 1 to the score each time it touches the right wall as well as the left paddle, and it also subtracts a point whenever it touches the left wall. When all it should be doing is adding one every time it touches the right wall.

```
    FRAMECLOCK = pygame.time.Clock() #set frame rate
    SURFACEDISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT)) #Clear the surface on refresh
    pygame.display.set_caption ('Pong') #title of window 

    ballX = WIDTH/2 - PLACEMENTMARKER/2 #ball position on X axis at the start
    ballY = HEIGHT/2 - PLACEMENTMARKER/2 #ball position on Y axis at the start
    playerOnePosition = (HEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2 #paddle one position at the start
    playerTwoPosition = (HEIGHT - PADDLESIZE) /2 #paddle two position at the start
    score = 0

    #Sets starting position movement
    ballDirX = -1 #-1 = left 1 = right
    ballDirY = -1 # -1 = up 1 = down

    paddle1 = pygame.Rect(PADDLEDISTANCE,playerOnePosition, PLACEMENTMARKER,PADDLESIZE) #paddle one drawing 
    paddle2 = pygame.Rect(WIDTH - PADDLEDISTANCE - PLACEMENTMARKER, playerTwoPosition, PLACEMENTMARKER,PADDLESIZE) #paddle two drawing 
    ball = pygame.Rect(ballX, ballY, PLACEMENTMARKER, PLACEMENTMARKER)#ball drawing

    Pong() #calling the game surface in main function
    paddles(paddle1) #calling paddle 1 main function
    paddles(paddle2) #calling paddle 2 in main function
    pongball(ball) #calling ball in main function 

    while True: #game Loop
        for event in pygame.event.get(): #Checks to see if program is quit
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() #system quit

        Pong() #Otherwise it performs these functions 
        paddles(paddle1)
        paddles(paddle2)
        pongball(ball)

        displayScore(str(score))
```

Comment: Are you setting score once you've ran checkscore? And where is the code that calls checkscore?

Comment: I only call display score with this - displayScore(str(score))

Comment: Not displayScore - where do you call checkscore?

Comment: Could you post a minimized example that we can run that replicates the error?

Comment: I've edited question. You can run that code and see exactly the problem I am experiencing

Answer (score 1):

The checkscore function was resetting the score, not subtracting it. It is also explicitly adding one when you hit it with the paddle.

I've modified the function to only add when hitting the right wall and not subtracting upon hitting the left:

```
def checkscore (paddle1, ball, score, ballDirX):
    #this is where the program resets after a point is scored 
    if ball.right == WIDTH - PLACEMENTMARKER:
        score += 1
        return score
    #no points scored, return score unchanged 
    else: return score
```

just substitute this function with the current `checkscore()` and everything should work

I'm assuming you've copied at least a large majority of this, make sure you read through everything thoroughly and try to understand each bit.